# Adding Multiple GameObjects LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am looking at making pong using LWJGL.

Well I was doing the LWJGL tutorials, by thebennybox, and had it working, I then wrote it out again when my old hard drive died (R.I.P). What I am trying to do is add multiple `GameObjects` and have them show up, I worked out that they are being added to the `GameObject objects` list. Here is the code in my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccs37jqm1b5oi84/lwjglGame.zip

It is a little too big to have on here but here is a main part:

This is from  Game.java:

```
private ArrayList<GameObject> objects;

    public Game() {
        objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

        GOplayer player = new GOplayer(0, Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight()/2);
        GOball ball = new GOball(Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth()/2-GOball.SIZE-2, Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight()/2);

        objects.add(player);
        objects.add(ball);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occur because of two problems.

1: Within the `GameObject` class your float variables `x` and `y` are static. Which they should not be!

2: Within the `Draw` class you call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` this should not be there as well, because what that does is clearing the depth and color buffer, which results in each time your render a "rect" using you `Draw.rect` that clears the screen, so in the end, only the last rendered "rect" will be shown!

Also you don't really need to clear the `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, since within the `initGL()` you disable it using `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` (though `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is disabled by default). And since your only working in 2D space then there are no actual depth, unless you're using the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` to sort the 2D space, while still using Z values.

#### Advice

Here is just some advice from me, if you don't 100% know all the main/basic keywords within Java, or just don't know how to use them correctly then starting off by creating a Game with OpenGL using LWJGL, will become extremly hard for you at some point. I suggest you start with something a lot easier or start off by reading or watching multiple tutorials about the basics of Java.

The reason I'm saying this is that you create a new instance of the class `GameObject` through `GOball`, `GOplayer` and `GObox` though inside the `GameObject` you have the float variables `x` and `y` those variables you've set as static, which mean that variables are shared and will always be the same. So when you create an `GOball` and set the `x` and `y` that sets the `x` and `y` though when you then create the `GOplayer` and set it's `x` and `y` to something else, that will affect the `GOball` as well so then they will have equally the same `x` and `y` always, since the variables are shared!